# React Component Infinite Re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a React component structure:

```
CookiesProvider
  | App
    | BrowserRouter
      | AppContext.Provider
        | Layout
          | Switch
            | Route path="all-products" component={Gallery}
```

When I refactor the code and pull the entire Switch/Routes structure into a stateless component or when I put the BrowserRouter component outside the CookieProvider component, the Gallery component gets infinitely re-rendered. But if I leave my structure in place, everything works fine.

I have logged the mounting and un-mounting of the Gallery component as well as the network calls.

Why could this be happing?

**Current code structure:**

```
// index.js
ReactDOM.render((
    <CookiesProvider>
        <Home />
    </CookiesProvider>
), document.getElementById('root'));

// render() of Home component
const galleryRefresh = this.state.galleryRefresh
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppContext.Provider value={this.state.context}>
            <Layout>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/all-products" component={()=> {
                        return <Gallery refresh={galleryRefresh} otherFilters={["type:clothes"]}/>
                    }}/>
                </Switch>
            </Layout>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

**When I refactor the Routes logic:**

```
// render() of Home Component
const galleryRefresh = this.state.galleryRefresh
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppContext.Provider value={this.state.context}>
            <Layout>
                <Route galleryRefresh={galleryRefresh}/>
            </Layout>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
)

// Routes stateless component
const Routes = ({galleryRefresh}) => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/all-watches" component={()=> {
            return <Gallery refresh={galleryRefresh} otherFilters={["type:Watch OR watch"]}/>
        }}/>
    </Switch>
)
```

Comment: Could you include your code before and after the refactor?

Comment: yes, give me a min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Route component, I am supposed to be using the `render` prop instead of the `component` prop.

```
       <Switch>
            <Route path="/all-products" render={()=> {
                return <Gallery refresh={galleryRefresh} otherFilters={["type:clothes"]}/>
            }}/>
        </Switch>
```